# Implementing a for loop in systemverilog

Tags: for-loop, testing, system-verilog, test-bench

I want to generate an automated input stimulus for my DUT. This input is going to different modules at the same time and working on this data. I want my input to be generated in an increasing manner. Like 0000,0001,0010,0011...1111
I tried using a `for` loop but it only uses the last data from the loop and works on that.

```
always_comb begin
  for (i=0, i<16; i=i+1)
  begin 
    data <= i;
  end 
end
```

When I give inputs individually like,

```
data = 8'd1;
#2;
data = 8'd2;
#2;
```

It works smoothly with all input values specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`always_comb` cannot have delays. At least per the IEEE1800 standard.

You can do something like this:

```
bit [3:0] data; // bit so the initial value is 0, not x
bit clk;
always #1 clk++; // or some other clock model
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  data <= data+1;
end
```

or something like this:

```
logic [3:0] data;
initial begin
  for (i=0, i<16; i=i+1) begin 
    data = i;
    #2;
  end 
end
```

Or some other similar code with time delay.

Comment: Is there some way to do this process using constraints?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "constraints"; SystemVerilog randomization `constraint` constructs or something else.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you if implement correctly. How to implement depends on they use case and desired behavior.